# How do I use list of type another class in TempDataDictionary?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using TempDataDictionary to hold values in my MVC project. I need to reduce number of TempDataDictionary. So I just made a list of class in another class.

```
 public class SurveyQuestions
    {
        public List<SurveyOptions> OptionsList { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, in TempDataDictionary which is : `public TempDataDictionary TempData { get; set; }`

In my controller class I was previously using tempdata in such a manner:
 `questionList = (List<SurveyQuestions>)TempData[Common.SURVEY_QUESTION_HOLDER];`

How do I use TempData in order to add and access values in list of **SurveyOption** type

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure I fully understand the question or what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: On my controller I was previously using Two tempdatadictionary for class SurveyQuestion and class SurveyOption. Now I want to reduce number of tempdatadictionary  to one So I  formed List of type SurveyOption in my View model of SurveyQuestion and Now I need to use tempdatadictionary in such a way to access list of type SurveyOption inside my SurveyQuestion class. So, how can I use the latter one?

Comment: Where you are getting the options list?

Comment: I have another Class of SurveyOptions, but in my SurveyQuestion class I have used "public List<SurveyOptions> OptionsList { get; set; }"